# Where can I find the security code in the Envelope

Tags: security, email, docusignapi

When DocuSign sends an email to a user requesting a signature, the View Documents button contains a link to a URL such as this:

https://demo.docusign.net/Member/EmailStart.aspx?a=564ffc65-28s7-402b-a499-cfec5526db3c&er=ac335504-8a6d-49a0-bfb6-3793887c0722

I know that the second parameter in the URL call is the recipient Id, which I can see in the envelope.  However, I cannot find the first parameter.

Is there anyway I can regenerate the URL?

The reason I ask is that we have a website with a message center.  Upon logging into our website, if the user has documents that require signature, I want to display a list of links for them to click and sign.

Comment: I agree with Mike, what you want is Embedding functionality.  That should work perfectly for your needs, and you don't have to wait for emails to arrive to start signing!  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a website with a message center and login I believe you should shift your paradigm of how you use DocuSign.  DocuSign has a concept of an embedded signer.  That means you notify the signer and when they log into your site you can make a web service call to present the person with a signing in an IFRAME or a separate window.

You can find the breakdown of that scenario in this code walkthrough:
http://iodocs.docusign.com/APIWalkthrough/embeddedSigning

A broader overview is here:
http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign

It is impossible for you to figure out or regenerate the GUIDs that are passed with envelope notification.  That's one of the security features of DocuSign notifications.

Hope this helps.